# getting unexpected token error in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

./src/component/Form2.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/Nikhil/Desktop/project/src/component/Form2.js: Unexpected token (196:27)

```
  194 |     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  195 |       <input {...register("firstName")} />
> 196 |       <p>{errors.firstName?.message}</p>
      |                            ^
  197 | 
  198 |       <input {...register("age")} />
  199 |       <p>{errors.age?.message}</p>
```

Comment: can you share how you get the `errors` object from the form ?

Comment: const { register, handleSubmit, formState:{ errors } } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

Answer (score 1):

Optional chaining (?.) is a feature introduced in ES2020.
Check if it is supported.